# Google maps no muestra la ubicacion actual en motorola?

Tags: android, google-maps

Estoy trabajando con google map donde mi app me debe montrar mi ubicación actual , la app funciona perfectamente, me muestra la ubicación actual , pero solo en teléfono Samsung , intente correrla en Motorola , solo me figura la mapa , pero no la ubicación indicada.. 
ahí esta mi código lo que intente de hacer...

```
 private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final float ZOOM = 15f;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2345;
private Boolean mLocationPermissions = false;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;


onCreate(){
/*....
*/
 initializarMap();
}
 private void initializarMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (mLocationPermissions) {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

}
private void getDeviceLocation(){
    Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        mCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                ZOOM,"My location");

                    }else{
                        Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e("MapsActivity.this", "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
private void mCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom,String title){

    Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "mCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
    mMap.mCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    MarkerOptions options= new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title);
    mMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

los celulares samsung en los cuales funciona la app tienen api , 22 y 23 y el motorola tiene api 27 
no se si me falta algun permiso o existe un permiso especial para motorola

los samsung tienen, 22 lollipop y 23 marshmollow y el motorola tiene 27 Oreo

Comment: Es algo conocido un problema con la inicialización de la antena con los motorola, configura lo que agrego en mi respuesta pero solo para que use GPS (lowest accuraccy) y prueba nuevamente

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys funciona , pero al contrario.. estaba configurado al lowest accurenccy , lo cambie a hight accurenccy:::: Pero existeuna forma de hacer  programáticamente  caso que el usuario no tiene idea del funcionamento??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad debe funcionar en cualquier dispositivo, **asegura que los servicios de geolocalización se encuentren activados**, este debe ser el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tu celular no cuenta con servicios de geolocalización definitivamente no podrá funcionar, actualmente sería extraño encontrar un móvil que no cuente con esta característica.

---

En realidad es un problema de diseño del celular de esta marca, si lo reinicias o si cambias el modo de geolocalización puede funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunas personas mencionan que lo "solucionan" pero en realidad no es así, simplemente cambian el modo.

https://thecellguide.com/gps-not-tracking-location-accurately-on-moto-g-53

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/motorola-one-vision/Motorola-One-Vision-GPS-Location-problem/td-p/4453079

Comment: Tambien , me parece muy raro , y la funcion geolocalizacion esta activada ...

Comment: muchas gracias , anda perfecto la app